# how to print a class pointer from within a vector container in c++?

Tags: c++, class, vector

```
class game_list
{
    public:
        string name;

};

game_list *pointer;


int main()
{
    vector<game_list*> mainVector;
    pointer=new game_list;
    cin>>pointer->name;

    mainVector.push_back(pointer);
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;

    cout << mainVector[1];

    return 0;
}
```

`game_list` is the class declaration. `vector<game_list*>` is the vector containing a bunch of `game_list` class pointers. I am trying to print the attributes of each `game_list` that inside the vector. So far I have tried, `mainVector[1].name` but seems like it doesn't work that way.Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *dereference* the pointer, just like you did above.

```
cout << mainVector[1]->name;
```

or

```
cout << (*(mainVector[1])).name;
```

Oh, and ForEveR got it right, vector indices start at 0. To get first element, you can also use `mainVector.front()`.

However, you probably don't want to use pointers at all. If you are sure you do, use `boost::ptr_vector` or a vector of `std` smart pointers. Right now this code has a **memory leak**.

Comment: this is for a class project and I am pretty sure my teacher doesn't have boost libraries :(

Comment: @user2086751 So add `boost::ptr_vector` to your sources. Boost libraries are (mostly) header-only. :)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly - indexes start from zero, so `mainVector[1]` - is not correct.
Secondly - if you dereference your pointer `mainVector[0]->name` or `(*mainVector[0]).name` will give correct value.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, you should be able to do:

```
cout << mainVector[0]->name << endl;
```